# Ubuntu Bind9 Zones

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind, domain-name

I have a quick question. I just setup DNS on one of our Ubuntu servers using Bind9. Now my question is do we need to setup a "zone" for every domain name? Or is there another option? What are the best practices for setting up different domains in Bind9?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a zone file for each top level root zone.

See this for an explanation: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ZVsbIZMfxPoJ:ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php%3Ft%3D699931+configure+multiple+domains+in+bind9&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com